# Strict in OPENJSON not work well

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2019

I've a table for save sub tasks data.

some time we change status of **sub tasks**, and i need both of them `id and status` in `@JsonStatus` parameter.

I wrote a stored procedure like below :

```
Declare @JsonStatus varchar(1000)       = '[{"id":147},{"id":151,"status2":2}]'
        ,@ID int

--TRUE FORMAT IS : '[{"id":147,"status":3},{"id":151,"status":2}]'
        Update dbo.TaskSub
        Set StatusID = JC.StatusID
        From OpenJson(@JsonStatus) 
        With(   ID                  bigint          'strict $.id',
                StatusID            tinyint         'strict $.status'
            ) as JC                                     
        Where dbo.TaskSub.id = @ID 
            AND dbo.TaskSub.ID = JC.ID
```

Some time developers not send a parameters but i cant raiserror or etc for them, id and status is mandatory.

I tried use `strict` statement by read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
if use `select` its work well like below :

```
Select *
From OpenJson(@JsonStatus) 
With(   ID                  bigint          'strict $.id',
        StatusID            tinyint         'strict $.status'
    ) as JC
```

but not worked in update and result is :

`(0 rows affected)`

Comment: Is `"status2":2` in the input JSON a typing error? And your `SELECT` statement using `strict` modifier (the last statement in the question) generates an error (and this is the expected behaviour with `strict` modifier, because first array item does not have `status` key).

Comment: @zhorov I use this update in `try catch` and use raisereor in try catch, but not work by this type of json. If you use this json by `select` statement raisereor worked well, but use update result is `0 rows affected` I'm confused.

Comment: Front and back end developers write  different source by this sp, some times they are say, one column not change by update, I found fault. They are send wrong json. I need raisereor when json is not true model. It's horibel, one column update and other column not update. All of them need update.